# Inline block not working with Python Django

Tags: python, css, django

So I have had this issue driving me crazy because I thought display: inline-block would work but it does not seem that way with Python Django. I am not sure if my css is bad or if it is my python code. I am very new at python so please excuse for how newb this may look.

Template:

```
<article class="article top-buffer
{% if article.is_featured %} featured{% endif %}
{% if not article.published %} unpublished{% endif %}">

{% if not detail_view %}
<div class="hg-box">
    <div>
        <img src="{% thumbnail article.featured_image 1200x400 crop subject_location=article.featured_image.subject_location %}" class="img-responsive product-main-image">
    </div>
    <div class="post-preview hg-post">
        <a href="{% namespace_url 'article-detail' article.slug namespace=namespace default='' %}">
            <h2 class="post-title">
            {% render_model article "title" "" "" "striptags" %} 
            </h2>
            {% if article.lead_in %}
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                {% if not detail_view %}
                    {% render_model article "lead_in" "" "" "truncatewords:'20'|striptags" %} 
                {% else %}
                    {% render_model article "lead_in" "" "" "striptags" %} 
                {% endif %}
            </h3>
            {% endif %}
        </a>
        {% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/date.html" %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}


{% if detail_view %}
    {% render_placeholder article.content language placeholder_language %}
{% endif %}
```

Here is my related CSS

```
.hg-post{background-color:white;padding:0 20px 20px 20px;border:1px solid #E6E3E8;margin-bottom:5px}
.hg-box{display: inline-block}
```

Post-Preview is just text related so I did not include it. Here is a picture of the site and what I want done.

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8ApN.png)

Looking at the picture might be a little confusing because there is some bootstrap involved. Which your right because in Django-CMS I can add rows and columns in house. Really cool took if you want an easy site builder and is provided by divio cloud. Here is a picture of the structure tree.

[structure picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCK7Z.png)

The thumbnails you see in the first image are apart of latest articles in the structure tree. The newsletter sign up is the newsform. Both are separated into their own columns.

If your wondering what the {% if not detail_view %} is than here is the code below for article detail.

```
{{% block title %}
{{ article.title }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
<!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url(
{% if article.featured_image_id %}
    {% thumbnail article.featured_image 1200x400 crop subject_location=article.featured_image.subject_location %}
{% else %}
    {% static 'img/post-bg.jpg' %}
{% endif %}
)">
    <div class="container hg-cover">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="post-heading">
                    <h1>{% render_model article "title" "" "" "striptags" %}</h1>
                    <h2 class="subheading">{% render_model article "lead_in" "" "" "striptags" %}</h2>
                    {% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/date.html" %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
{% endblock %}

{% block newsblog_content %}
{% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/article.html" with detail_view="true" %}

{% static_placeholder "newsblog_social" %}

<ul class="pager">
    {% if prev_article %}
        <li><a href="{{ prev_article.get_absolute_url }}">{% trans "Previous Article" %}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    <li><a href="{% namespace_url "article-list" %}">{% trans "Back to Overview" %}</a></li>
    {% if next_article %}
        <li><a href="{{ next_article.get_absolute_url }}">{% trans "Next Article" %}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}}enter code here
```

Any recommendations would be a huge help. I apologize if this is hard to follow. I can certainly provide more info if needed.

Comment: Try making the box smaller. It won't inline if there's not enough space for two boxes to fit.

Comment: This is only css issue, not django. Do you have a semicolon after the inline block rule: `.hg-box{display: inline-block;}` ? In the code above you don't.

Comment: The semi-colon was not there because it came from the css.min file and yes I tried to make the boxes smaller but had no luck.

Comment: I figured it out. My CSS affected the template in which those articles are in but that leads to a new problem. Latest articles and featured articles share the same template so now I have gone backwards several steps.